# Telerik Grid Double Click Display Twice the Number of Clicks

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a telerik grid that I am using to do a post to the server when the user double click on a row.  It appears to work fine until I place an alert in the code and notice some odd behaviors. When I double click on a row for the first time, the alert comes up twice and continues to display twice the number of times that I click. I mean - it comes up twice the first time, 4 times the second time, 6 times the third times, and it continues on. Below is the scripts that I am using to call the grid.

```
function DisplayStudent(e) {
    if (IsStudentGradeAvailable == "True") {
        $('tr', this).live('dblclick', function () {
            var row = e.row;
            var StudentId= row.cells[0].innerHTML;
            var StudentGrade= row.cells[1].innerHTML;
            var data = { "StudentId= ": StudentId= , "StudentGrade": StudentGrade };
            var url = '@Url.Action("Student", "StudentGrade")';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'text',
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Success");
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("Error");
                }

            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Live attaches an event handler.  You want one event handler, so you should call the live() method only once.  Given your code, this implies that DisplayStudent() should only be called once.

If DisplayStudent() is called n times, you will have attached n event handlers, each of which alerts you when you click.

Comment: I see...Another word, I should close the popup window and reopen if they want o see more student or handle it a different way.